# Android studio 2.1.2 is not opening on Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, android-studio-2.1

Whenever i start opening the Android Studio 2.1.2 on Windows 10 it shows the following window:

[image: this]

which doesn't proceed ahead to show opened window of Android Studio. I have recently installed Windows 10 using CD. Does anyone have same problem and knows how to solve it ?

Comment: did you installed java ?  what is your system specs  Ram, processor speed , free space on C Drive ?

Comment: Anything in the log (C:\Users\<yourid>\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log)? Or how about using VisualVM to take a threaddump?

Comment: i have Java installed. System specs: RAM = 4GB free space =65GB

Comment: I am also facing same problem my system specs are intel core i5, 4gb ram, 102GB free space on C drive

Comment: I have tried "disable.android.first.run=true" line in idea.properties file that helped me to proceed from screen but on the next screen I am not able to perform next things like import/create projects. even loading SDK takes infinite time. not success to start the studio :(

Comment: i installed android studio 1.4 and downloaded android studio 2.1.2 update and extracted in android studio folder in C drive. Just open Studio file from the bin folder of android studio and it worked for me.